# Trying to understand patented Collatz-based PRNG algorithm

Tags: algorithms, cryptography, collatz-conjecture

I am trying to understand the following [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) algorithm patented by IBM:

- [Efficient and low power encrypting and decrypting of data](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8130956), US8130956B2.

> The present invention relates to the field of computer data encrypting and decrypting, especially for mobile equipments like PDA, mobile phones, smart cards and the like, which need a good trade-off between computing speed, power consumption and security strength. Embodiments of the invention provide encrypting/decrypting methods implementing simple data operation. Such methods are based on generating a pseudo-random sequence through a function of the Collatz (or Syracuse) family from a starting number used as a secret key.

This algorithm is about [generating pseudo-random numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) with Collatz sequences and generalized Collatz functions. Unfortunately, it is written in such an unclear way that I don't understand almost anything.

Is someone able to explain in a clear way what the presented algorithm does? I am pretty sure it can be described in a few lines, but for some reasons the authors did everything to make it obscure.

Comment: Note that [Patents SE](https://patents.stackexchange.com) exists.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo oh, thanks, I didn't know that. I'm still interested in this topic, but I understood this publication a little bit better already.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I already understand everything in that patent. So I could delete the question or post answer by myself. But there is quite much to explain. I'm not sure I will find a time to do it accurately and reliably.

Comment: If you ever find the time, please consider posting a sketch of an answer